# Getting an attribute error on something I explicitly defined in init

Tags: python, initialization, pickle

I'm trying to make a config file manager that stores dictionaries in a pickle file, in a config folder in the same directory. I'm having issues with a pesky AttributeError that claims I don't have an attribute '_name', which I defined in the first line of **init**().

The main program has 2 classes, one inheriting from Exceptions (the error class) and the other inheriting from dict (the main class). The init takes a name and finds if the file exists. If it doesn't, then an empty dictionary is written to the given file.

I receive the error when I:
1. open an existing file to print the keys
2. write a key and value pair to an existing file
3. try and get a key from the dictionary

I've tried not calling dict.**setitem** in **init** and nothing changed, I still get the error. I tried just loading the file while doing *absolutely nothing else* to it, and couldn't get it to work.

```
import os
import pickle

class ConfigDict(dict):
    '''
        This class is responsible for all main functions.

        Pass a string as an argument without a file type.

        Keywords such as 'database' and 'aiconstructer' work well.
    '''
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name+'.pickle'
        if not os.path.isfile(self._name):
            with open(self._name, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump('{}', f)
        with open(self._name,'rb') as f:
            obj = pickle.load(f)
        if len(obj) > 2:
            for k in obj.keys():
                dict.__setitem__(self, k, obj[k])

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not key in self.keys():
            raise ConfigKeyError(self, key)
        return dict.__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)
        with open(self._name, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self, f)
```

The Traceback is as follows:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interface.py", line 12, in <module>
      test = ConfigDict('alpha')
  File "/home/bear/Desktop/Config/confdict.py", line 35, in __init__
      obj = pickle.load(f)
  File "/home/bear/Desktop/Config/confdict.py", line 47, in __setitem__
      with open(self._name, 'wb') as f:
AttributeError: 'ConfigDict' object has no attribute '_name'
```

The code for interface.py that initiates this is:

```
import sys
from confdict import ConfigDict, ConfigKeyError

test = ConfigDict('alpha')

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    key = sys.argv[1]
    val = sys.argv[2]
    print('Writing')
    test[key] = val
    print('Done')

elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    key = sys.argv[1]
    print('{}:{}'.format(key,test[key]))

else:
    print('Keys   :   Values')
    print('-----------------')
    for k in test.keys():
        print('{}   :   {}'.format(k,test[k]))
```

I expect to be able to load the contents of the pickle file into self, but instead I get the AttributeError. Is it something I'm doing grammatically wrong, or is there a rule that I forgot to follow? Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Try running the code you posted here so you can get it to actually recreate the problem, please. I added some missing imports, got rid of "config" in the path (because it was generating an OS error) and ended up with pickle raising __buildints.EOFError: Ran out of input__ (the file alpha.pickle appears to be empty after the pickle.dump)

Comment: Also, not that I ever got there, but what should sys.argv have? For a [mcve] I would prefer you just set the inputs directly in the code, but what are they?

Comment: I took out import statements and docstrings for brevity, sorry about that I’ll put them back in. Taking ‘config’ out of name is acceptable, it’s just a path to a directory for the pickle files. Interface either takes zero(print all key/ value pairs), one (return a value for the key given) or two (set a key/ value pair in the dictionary) arguments. I added it because I’m not sure what brought up the issue, it showed in the stack trace so I thought it might be somewhat relevant.

Comment: Sorry, tried again. Your code is way too fragile. If so many things aren't set up exactly like you expect, so many different things happen. Does that directory exist? Is the file already there? I get different errors, but never the ones you get. Try stepping through one line at a time. What you say happens is NOT what I am seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I'll figure it out.